# Is there a certain threshold over which to accept or reject predictors based on correlation values with the target variable?

Tags: statistics, feature-selection, data-science-model, correlation, kaggle

I have been working on the **[Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)**. After some feature manipulation, I printed out the correlation values between my target variable `Survived` and all the other predictors. Based on these values, I would like to decide if any variables can be removed from the training set.

```
Survived  :  1.000000,
Pclass    : -0.338481,
Sex       : -0.543351,
Age       : -0.037059,
Fare      :  0.302002,
Embarked  : -0.167675,
Title     :  0.407753,
IsAlone   :  0.163157
```

Correlation values of `Survived` with other predictors.

I am not quite sure of what to do with the `Age` feature. Maybe try a different kind of feature manipulation on it?

Comment: What does the Title column signify? is it supposed to be Ticket as per dataset.

Comment: the title is basically grouping of the passengers on the categories of Mr. , Mrs. , Master and Miss